# Javascript regex unable to replace certain special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this Javascript regex:

```
 body = body.replace(/[\x80-\xFF]/g,"#");
```

which I am hoping to use to replace characters in the table [here](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html). However I am unable to replace the characters highlighted in red on the table in that page. I couldn't comprehend why. Can someone enlighten me on why it is happening like that and what the workaround? Thank you.

Comment: for the sake of being able to quickly reproduce your issue can you provide a sample body text here?

Comment: Agree.  Need some examples of target text and desired result.

Comment: Because `\x##` is for ASCII Characters.  `\x####` is for Unicode.  You're going to have to use the Unicode Code point to the left of the code points you're trying to use.  For instance, `body = body.replace(/\x20AC/g,"#");` will replace all Euro Signs with pound symbols.

Comment: sorry, `\u####` is for unicode.

Comment: @SamIam: Sorry my sample message has some private data and it is too much work for me to edit it and post here.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan  I know it works if I deal with characters individually. But I want one regex that covers all the chars in that table.

Comment: @ChaitanyaM than make a [fake sample message that has the minimum amount of data necessary](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: Why not Invert the issue?  Instead of defining which characters are illegal, focus only on defining the legal characters, and replacing anything that doesn't match.  `/[^\x20-\xFF\x09-\x0D]/g`, for instance, will match anything that's not a printable ascii character.

Comment: My upstream system has trouble dealing with chars like ä á etc. So I just used  body = body.replace(/[\u00A1-\u00FF]/g,"#"); body = body.replace(/[\u0152-\u2122]/g,"@");   I cant do away with just one because the range is not contiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is to use a Unicode range instead, this works (for what I presume you're trying to do) when I try it on your example page in the console:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/[\u0152-\u2122]/g,"#");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @mVChr. I got away using the following 2 lines:

body = body.replace(/[\u00A1-\u00FF]/g,"#");

body = body.replace(/[\u0152-\u2122]/g,"@");